# When inserting data using Room in Android, get Single<Long> as return instead of Long

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am inserting data in SQLite DB using Room as shown below.
Insert queries can return void, long or long array. Is there any way I can get Single as I am using RxJava to insert and retrieve objects on worker thread.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun addNotification(notification: Notification): Single<Long>
```

Comment: Methods annotated with `@Insert` can return either `void, long, Long, long[], Long[]` or `List<Long>`. So, I think your case currently not have solution.

Comment: AFAIK, that is not supported. With Room, the reason for reactive return types (particularly `Observable` and `LiveData`) is not for threading, but for delivery of updates. That only makes sense for queries, where changes to data causes changes to query results that might need to be re-delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Since Version 2.1.0-alpha01, @Insert annotated method can return Single.

> Additional Rx Return Types Support: DAO methods annotated with @Insert, @Delete or @Update now support Rx return types **Completable**, **Single** and **Maybe**. b/63317956

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.1.0-alpha01

So you just need to use the latest release available and you are ready to go :

```
implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0-alpha06")
```